# Sublime Text: How to set up begining of line/end of line shortcuts to match the shell?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I've been using Sublime Text for a little while now (on MacBook Pro), and want to make it keystroke compatible with the shell.

In the shell, to jump to the beginning/end of line I press fn+Left/fn+Right.

In Sublime Text, I understand how to set up key bindings for fn+Left/fn+Right, but I [see no key name](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html?highlight=binding#bindable-keys) for the fn key (not the f1, f2, etc. function keys, I am referring to the key marked "fn").

How can I make this work in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess I was making it too hard on myself.

1. the <kbd>fn</kbd> button does not have a key name in Sublime Text.
2. <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> is read as <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>.  Simply mapping `home` and `end` did the job.

Specifically:

```
Sublime Text | Preferences | Key Bindings - User
```

- Add the following between the [ ]:

  ```
    { "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": { "to": "hardbol" } },
    { "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": { "to": "hardeol" } }
  ```

---

I discovered this by opening up the SublimeText console:

```
ctrl+`
sublime.log_input(True)
```

Now, typing any keys reveal their Sublime Text key names. <kbd>fn</kbd> did not elicit a response, but <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> yielded <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>.

```
sublime.log_input(False)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Open menu `Sublime Text` > `Preferences` > `Key Bindings`

Add the following to the array (between square brackets `[]`):

```
{ "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol"} },
{ "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol"} },
{ "keys": ["shift+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["shift+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": true } }
```

You can now use the following combinations:

- Go to beginning of line: <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Go to end of line: <kbd>End</kbd>
- Select from cursor position to beginning of line: <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
- Select from the cursor position to end of line: <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

For me(on MBP):

<kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> worked as <kbd>Home</kbd>

<kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> worked as <kbd>End</kbd>

Without changing any configuration in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

For adding the keybindings to ST4 on Macbook Pro (to match the windows ones with home and end), this worked

```
[
    { "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol"} },   
    { "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol"} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bof"} },   
    { "keys": ["ctrl+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof"} },
    { "keys": ["shift+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": true} },
    { "keys": ["shift+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": true } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": true} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bof", "extend": true } },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is agnostic to Sublime and will also work with other programs (including Chrome etc)

`mkdir -p ~/Library/KeyBindings/ && touch ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`

Open `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`
and paste

```
{
    "\UF729"  = moveToBeginningOfLine:; // home
    "\UF72B"  = moveToEndOfLine:; // end
    "$\UF729" = moveToBeginningOfLineAndModifySelection:; // shift-home
    "$\UF72B" = moveToEndOfLineAndModifySelection:; // shift-end
}
```

You will have to quit and re-open Sublime Text (or any application) for this to take effect.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16137/234304